# Running an ODBC_FETCH_ARRAY in a WHILE loop is not echoing results

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, odbc, php-7

So I have this code that's been working on every web page I've written but now all of a sudden it's not working.

```
<?php  
global $conn1;
$conn1=@odbc_connect("lib", "user", "password");
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$TheDateAndTime=date("m/d/y       H:i:s");
$prodWindowDate = '1'.date('ymd', strtotime('- 14 days'));
global $prodWindowDate;
$tmID=$_GET['tmID'];
global $tmID;
?>
```

The above part I have on every page and it works flawlessly.

```
<p align="center">This page is a work in progress.<br>Please be patient as all the kinks are worked out.<br>Thank you.</p>
<div id="statsForTMs">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center table-stripped">
            <thead>
                <th colspan="8">stats for <?php echo $tmID; ?></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>PA</th>
                <th>Hours in PA</th>
                <th>TC</th>
                <th>TP</th>
                <th>TL</th>
                <th>LPH</th>
                <th>PPH</th>
<?php
$ptlStats="SELECT 
        A.DATE_STAMP,
        A.PA,
        cast(ROUND(A.ACTIVE_TIME_ACCUM/3600,2) as decimal(10,2)) AS HOURS,
        A.NT,
        A.TP,
        A.TL,
        cast(ROUND(A.TL/(ROUND(A.ACTIVE_TIME_ACCUM/3600,2))) as numeric(5,0)) as LPH,
        FLOOR(A.PPH)
    FROM 
        LIB.TABLE A
    WHERE A.DATE_STAMP >= '$prodWindowDate'
        AND A.PI = '$tmID'
    ORDER BY A.DATE_STAMP DESC ";

$resultPTLstats=@odbc_exec($conn1, $ptlStats);
while($row=@odbc_fetch_array($resultPTLstats)){
echo '<tr><td>'.$row['DATE_STAMP'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['PA'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['HOURS'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['NT'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['TP'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['TL'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['LPH'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['PPH'].'</td>
      </tr>';
}
@odbc_close($conn1);
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I echo out $tmID or $prodWinowDate outside of the SQL and WHILE loop, I get results. 
I've tested the SQL in WinSQL and it works properly. I'm unable to echo out those results, which is what I need.

*Two of the rows are Primary Keys, not that it should matter.*

The way I've set up the WHILE loop has worked on every other page I've created. I've been staring at this for three days and I'm completely lost. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

edit: Taking out the masks, I'm left with `Token � was not valid. Valid tokens: ( NEW FINAL TABLE UNNEST LATERAL XMLTABLE JSON_TABLE <IDENTIFIER>.`

Comment: Masking errors with `@` is bad practice. You should be checking them instead.

Comment: You're not wrong, it's just that our database goes down multiple times per day and I'd rather not have a web page not load due to our database being down for backup.

Comment: But the fact you're getting no data is almost certainly due to an error, so if you mask them you'll never know why...

Comment: You know what, I did forget about that. I've been using that snippet of code for so long and it's just worked that I completely forgot about it. Removing the mask shows "Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: <IDENTIFIER>., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect"

Comment: It seems to think you have an extra comma in the query although I can't see one...

Comment: Yeah, me neither. It did just populate a new error, which is always fun. `Token � was not valid. Valid tokens: ( NEW FINAL TABLE UNNEST LATERAL XMLTABLE JSON_TABLE <IDENTIFIER>.`

Answer (score 0):

The last error I got was `Token � was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + * - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS HASH.`

Dropping a `utf8_decode` in front of the $ptlStats in the $resultPTLstats cleared the error. `$resultPTLstats=@odbc_exec($conn1, utf8_decode($ptlStats));`